# How can I connect a wireless access point to an existing network (with a proxy)?

Tags: wireless-networking, proxy, dhcp

im new here, hope you guys can help me out.
i was tasked to do the network (wireless and wired) of our new department in our company.
our existing network has dhcp server(Windows Server 2003) and a Proxy Server.
heres what ive done so far.

```
main network (dhcp and proxy server)  
  |  
  |  
switch (for wired users) - no problem here, user can connect to the internet.  
  |  
  |
access point (for wireless users) - AP dhcp is disabled and is connected to Switch  
user have the correct ip address coming from the dhcp server(Windows Server 2003)  
users cannot connect to the internet.
```

what is missing here guys, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

That in general is a working setup - but is it a transparent proxy?  If not, the wireless clients may be trying to connect directly to the internet.  Make sure they're configured to use the proxy.

Comment: hi JimG. i have configured the users internet options to use the proxy, i tested it using the wired, and its working, but when i try to connect trough the AP, i cannot connect to the internet.